# Matplotlib - Unable to save figure as eps file when using latex to render text

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using latex to render text in matplotlib but I'm unable to save the figure if any text has latex environments in it.

Simplified code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('PS')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

s = (r"\begin{description}"
     r"\item[someitem:] blah blah blah blah blah \\"
     r"Some more text that I want to add to my plot"
     r"\item[anotheritem:] This is even more text"
     r"\end{description}")
plt.text(0,0,s)
plt.savefig('myfig.eps')
```

I get a generic latex error when I try to save it.

> ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.

However, I don't think there's anything wrong with my latex. I tried compiling a latex document with just the above snippet in it and it worked fine.

Interestingly, the plot gets rendered if I use an interactive backend with ipython/jupyter-notebook but I am still unable to save the figure as ps or eps file. It also works if I remove the `\begin{...} ... \end{...}`

How do I save the figure as a ps/eps file if I use a latex environment in the text?

Comment: Try using `plt.savefig('myfig.eps', format='eps', dpi=5000)`

Comment: @Bazingaa The output format is already deduced from the extension of the filename and I don't think changing the dpi will achieve anything. I tried it anyway and got the same error message

Comment: While compiling your TeX file, are you sure you are using `ps` or `ps2pdf` option somewhere in your compiler settings?

Comment: No I don't think so. But I don't see how that's relevant to python? Is there some rc option like `text.texarguments`? Also as I mentioned it works if I don't use any latex environments

Comment: Hmm, I misread your question. I get the same error. Saving as `.pdf` works fine though but that's not what you are interested in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be in [vertical mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155746/162773). You can wrap your text in a `parbox`:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('PS')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

s = (r"\parbox{4in}{"
     r"\begin{description}"
     r"\item[someitem:] blah blah blah blah blah \\"
     r"Some more text that I want to add to my plot"
     r"\item[anotheritem:] This is even more text"
     r"\end{description}"
     r"}"
    )

plt.text(0,0,s)
plt.savefig('myfig.eps')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I stumbled across that tex.exchange answer a few hours ago but didn't really have the time to write an answer.